# Explanation of the Finite sub-families criterion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I'm studying for the exam in probability theory (which is more oriented on a Measure Theory course), and I would like some clarification about this "Finite subfamilies criterion", which states:

Be $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$ two families of random variables, for $i \in I$ a set of indexes.
$(X_i): \Omega \to E_i$, $(Y_i): \Omega' \to E_i$.
Let us defined
$$X: \Omega \to \Pi_i E_i \qquad \qquad Y: \Omega \to \Pi_i E_i$$

Then $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$ are isonomous iff $\forall j = \{ i_1, \ldots i_k \}$ we have that $(X_j)$ and $(Y_j)$ are isonomous.

(Note: "isonomous" means they have the same law (or also: they are identically distributed))

**Proof**

For $\{ I_i, \ldots i_k \} = J \subset I$, be $A_i \in \mathcal{E}_i$, where $\mathcal{E}_i$ are $\sigma-$ algebras. Then

$$X(P)\left(\bigcap_{j = 1}^k \left\{ \Pi_{ij}^{-1}(A_j) \right\} \right) = P\left(\bigcap_{j = 1}^k X_{ij}^{-1} (A_j)\right)$$
$$ = P'\left(\bigcap_j \left\{ Y_{ij}^{-1}(A_j)\right\} \right) = Y(P) \left(\bigcap_j \Pi_{ij}^{-1}(A_j)\right)$$

Then the two laws are equal over the rectangles which form a basis for the product $\sigma-$ algebra, hence they are identical over the whole space $\left(\Pi_i E_i,\ \otimes_i \mathcal{E}_1\right)$.

**My Doubts**

- : Well, can you simply explain me better all this? I understood very little, and also I cannot find anything similar online...

Thank you!